# Google Maps SDK Xamarin.iOS show MapView in UIView via Storyboard

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using Google Maps SDK for my Xamarin.iOS app and i got an problem.

I want to put MapView into specific ***UIView***(that was created on Storyboard) and that is no so easy as expected.

At current moment i have tried to put **MapView** class into my **UIView** class(in native iOS Development its an solution),but it didn't worked.

Also i have tried to do something like this:

```
//init google SDK stuff
MyViewWhereIWantToPutGoogleMaps.AddSubview(MapView); // and the same,no effect
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember you need to indicate the CGRect for the MapView object.

If you want it to cover the whole space in `MyViewWhereIWantToPutGoogleMaps` you just do:

```
var frame = MyViewWhereIWantToPutGoogleMaps.Frame;
var googleMaps = new Google.Maps.MapView (new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, frame.Width, frame.Height));

MyViewWhereIWantToPutGoogleMaps.AddSubview (googleMaps);
```

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Great,it worked. Thanks!
Another question : why i cant overlay with other item?

Comment: @VetaLio you mean like showing other items visible over the Map?

Comment: yeah,pretty like that. ill do .gif animation for visualization(its better to understand). Hold on!

Comment: Please see attached .gif https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zE1x.gif . That the problem,also other view not appear on view,where is located google maps :\

Comment: See... how are you doing the overlay? Open a new thread in SO so it's not kept in the comments of this one.

Comment: any idea why that happens? Can we start chat?

Comment: to appear your overlay use .InsertSubview(view, 0) instead of AddSubview